# How can I return a list based on a condition on the referencing elements of the list

Tags: xtend, xpand

I want to return a list of elements of 'ListOfObjects' that are being referenced by 'SomeOtherObject' with it's(SomeOtherObject's)  attribute satisfying the condition.
I'm trying this code:

```
ParentObj.ListOfObjects.select(e|e.referencingContainers.typeSelect(SomOtherObject).attr.isValid());
```

'ListOfObjects' extracts a list of particular objects from the 'ParentObj'.But the above code gives me nothing. Please help me out in figuring out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, in the above piece of code, the result of the expression inside the select returns a list and not an a boolean. To make it boolean I'd have to rewrite the code this way:

```
ParentObj.ListOfObjects.select(e|e.referencingContainers.typeSelect(SomOtherObject).select(el|el.attr.isValid()).size > 0);
```

The select inside the select along with the check for size is what made the difference there.

Comment: Or instead of doing `select(el|el.attr.isValid()).size > 0)` `exists(el|el.attr.isValid())` can also be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **extension** to find objects that reference a specific object: `org::eclipse::xtend::util::stdlib::crossref`

You can also specify conditions in the same way. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.xpand.doc/help/ch04s02.html?path=61_1_2_1_8#N126BB) is more information about Cross References Extensions.